# How to close a malware tab in chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, malware

A webpage got redirected to a "virus alert" malware page and I can't close it.

Deleted the cache, both the general tablet cache as well as the chrome cache, deleted the "unimportant data", did "force stop", restarted the tablet, but chrome still automatically opens that tab where I left off.

Google should make an option to close all tabs on exit or otherwise.

Comment: Run anti Malware app and see if that fixes

Comment: Deleted cache, data of chrome(Have you stopped[force stop] chrome before this operation). Try reinstall chrome  .

Comment: Yes, did force stop.

Comment: And "delete data"? Another thing to try: the navigation bar at the bottom of the screen has an entry for "tab overview". Tapping that, the screen looks like "recent apps", just showing the tabs of Chrome. From there you should be able to close the tab (just saw the same thing on another device a couple of days ago, and while not even the "back" button had any effect, this approach worked).

Comment: Well you can try entering a different address in the chrome address bar

Comment: @anurag No you can't

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the screen with the tab in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue Resolved:** 
Clicked on a link in another app that opened in chrome, and then by pressing X on as many tabs as fast as i can, was able to close that tab.

(PS Chrome should make a feature whereby you can close all the tabs automatically all at once instead of individually each one.)